# Cognito social auth should result in a session token

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, amazon-cognito-facebook

My backend expects the cognito session token that is result of user logging in with cognito user pool.

However, when user authenticates with facebook, no session token is being returned. Is there a way, to have the social authentication result in a session token? I'm talking about the combination of id token, refresh token, and access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document describes setting up a federated auth provider flow which results in ID, Access, and Refresh tokens:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html